# Difference between auto, 0, and no z-index?

Tags: html, css, z-index

What is the difference between:

1. `z-index: auto`
2. `z-index: 0`
3. no `z-index` at all

All the above scenarios are for a `div` that encloses two `div`s, `div1` and `div2` each having a `z-index` which is `9` and `10` respectively.

The enclosing `div` is in the stacking context of HTML.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Not specifying `z-index` is the same as `z-index: auto`; that is its initial value.

`auto` and `0` mean the same thing if your element doesn't create its own stacking context; e.g. it is not positioned as relative, absolute or fixed.

If your enclosing `div` isn't positioned, then whatever you set its `z-index` to doesn't matter; it and all its contents will participate in the stacking context of `html`, and its descendants will always be positioned in front of it.

Answer (score 31):

What @BoltClock said is right.

> Not specifying `z-index` is the same as `z-index: auto;` that is its initial value.

About `z-index: 0` it's important to note the following:

`z-index: 0` creates a stacking context while `z-index: auto` do not. You can check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) for more information about this.

In most cases this won't affect the rendered elements.

The following is an example where it matters:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  top: 32px;
  left: 32px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

#example-auto {
  display: inline-block;
}

#example-0 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div id="example-auto">
  <div class="box red">
    <div class="box green" style="z-index: 1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box blue"></div>
</div>

<div id="example-0">
  <div class="box red" style="z-index: 0">
    <div class="box green" style="z-index: 1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box blue"></div>
</div>
```

In both cases, red and blue are siblings with a `position: relative` and green is a child of red with `position: relative` and `z-index: 1`:

- Root

  - Red: `position: relative`

    - Green: `position: relative; z-index: 1`
  - Blue: `position: relative`

In the first example, green will be positioned above red and blue. This is because it has a `z-index: 1`, so a stacking context is created and put above the root context.

In the second example, green will be positioned above red, but below blue. This is because red has `z-index: 0`, so it creates a stacking context at the same level of blue. So green will be above red (because green also creates a stacking context), but below blue because it's trapped in the context of red.

---

Here's a more practical example. We want an `object` element wrapped in an `a` element. When the data is an svg, the anchor will be ignored when hovering over the svg. To fix this, we can use `z-index: 0` for `a` and `z-index: -1` for `object`.

```html
<a href="#test1" style="display: inline-block; width: 100px">
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/star.svg"></object>
</a>

<a href="#test2" style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; position: relative; z-index: 0">
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/star.svg" style="position: relative; z-index: -1"></object>
</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

`z-index:0` is always the "default layer" (the layer in which all elements without an explicit `z-index` reside), and `z-index:auto` means: "*Sets the stack order equal to its parent*".
Since all the children of a parent by default start in the "z-layer 0" - **relative to their parent**, then, in-affect, `z-index:auto` and `z-index:0` means the same thing: they will both be in the same "layer", and their stacking order will be according to the default stacking rules, which you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_and_float).

Answer (score 2):

## z-index: auto

Sets the stack order equal to its parents. This is default.

## z-index:0

does nothing

## z-index:not

Sets the stack order equal to its parents same as auto.

## z-index:inherit

Specifies that the z-index should be inherited from the parent element

Reference for further reading and testing:

[Link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: Like BoltClock said, `z-index:0` makes it behind siblings that don't have `z-index: <n>`.

Comment: @jasonszhao, that's not true. e.g. see: https://jsfiddle.net/jf3bgL9z/3/